# If a sequence $( x_ n )_{ n ∈ \mathbb{N}} \in X$ satisfies $d ( x _n ,x_{n +1 }) < α_ n$ , for all $n \in N$ , then the sequence is convergent.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

> Let  $(X,d)$  be  a  complete  metric  space  and  $(α_n)_{n \in
> > \mathbb{N}}$ a  sequence  of  positive  real  numbers  such  that 
>   $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \alpha_n$ converges.  Show that if a sequence
>   $(x_n)_{n \in N} \in X$ satisfies $d ( x _n ,x_ {n +1} ) < α_ n$ , for
>   all $n \in N$ , then the sequence is convergent.

Comment: Presumably you mean $d(x_n, x_{n+1}) < \alpha_n$??? Note that $d(x_m,x_n) \le d(x_m,x_{m+1})+\cdots+ d(x_{n-1},x_n)$.

Comment: Hello and welcome. What is your question? What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I believe the "complete-spaces" tag is used for questions of showing a space is complete rather than just working in a complete space.

Comment: Why haven't you accepted the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \alpha_n$ converges if and only if $\forall \varepsilon > 0\;\exists N\in\mathbb{N}\;\forall n\geq m\geq N: \sum_{k=m}^n \alpha_n < \varepsilon$, and that $d(x_{n+m},x_n) \leq \sum_{k=n}^{m-1} d(x_{k+1},x_k)$.